# How can I detect when I've copied something new to the clipboard in Python?

Tags: python, clipboard

I'm trying to create a basic translator program with DeepL API that automatically translates what is on the clipboard, rather than having to run it everytime I decide to copy something new.

I've tried googling a solution but all I can find is how I can paste whatever is in my clipboard, which is just half of what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm not sure how to describe it properly but I want my program to automatically run whenever I copy anything new. If I'm understanding that correctly, that's just how I can use the contents of my clipboard but every time I want to translate something new, I would need to manually run it again

Comment: Check out https://medium.com/@prashantgupta24/how-to-create-your-own-clipboard-manager-using-python-and-tkinter-e693aa27fffc.  He created his personal clipboard using tkinter.

Comment: For win32: https://abdus.dev/posts/monitor-clipboard/